# Two Problems in Goldstein's step in deriving the Lagrangian

Tags: classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism

We have d'Alembert's principle:
$$\sum_{i} (F_{i} - \dot{p}_{i}) \cdot \delta r_{i} = 0.\tag{1.45}$$

We have $$\sum_{j}F_{i} \cdot \delta r_{i} = \sum_{j} Q_{j}\delta q_{j}.\tag{1.48}$$

We have $$\sum_{i} m_{i}\ddot r_{i} \cdot \frac{\partial r_{i}}{\partial q_{j}} = \sum_{i} \left[\frac{d}{dt}\left(m_{i}v_{i} \cdot \frac{\partial v_{i}}{\partial \dot q_{j}}\right) - m_{i}v_{i} \cdot \frac{\partial v_{i}}{\partial q_{j}}\right].$$

Substituting the second and third equations into the first one:

$$\sum_{j} \left\{ \frac{d}{dt} \left[ \frac{\partial}{\partial \dot q_{j}} \left( \sum_{j} \frac{1}{2}m_{i}v^{2}_{i}\right)\right] - \frac{\partial}{\partial q_{j}}\left(\sum_{i} \frac{1}{2}m_{i}v^{2}_{i}\right) - Q_{j} \right\} \delta q_{j}.$$

My first question is how did Goldstein switch the signs in d'Alembert's principle?

My second question is the following. We have (after substituting in the definition of kinetic energy):

$$\frac{d}{dt}\left(\frac{T}{\partial \dot q_{j}}\right) - \frac{\partial T}{\partial q_{j}} = Q_{j}.\tag{1.53}$$

If we define $Q_{j}$ to be a conservative generalized force, then $$Q_{j} = -\frac{\partial V}{\partial q_{i}}.\tag{1.54}$$

Substituting the definition of $Q_{j}$ and Goldstein gets:

$$\frac{d}{dt}\left(\frac{\partial T}{\partial \dot q_{j}}\right) - \frac{\partial(T-V)}{\partial q_{i}} = 0.\tag{1.55}$$

But if I substitute in $Q_{j}$:
$$\frac{d}{dt}\left(\frac{T}{\partial \dot q_{j}}\right) - \frac{\partial T}{\partial q_{j}} = -\frac{\partial V}{\partial q_{i}}.$$

I do not understand how Goldstein was able to get $\frac{\partial (T-V)}{\partial q_{i}}.$

Comment: Which sign specifically?

Comment: It looks like Goldstein flipped d'Alermbert's principle to $(\dot{p} - F) \cdot \delta r = 0$ without multiplying the equation by $-1$

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/12361/2451

Comment: That answers my first question. @Qmechanic can you please explain why the minuses do not cancel in my second question? Why shouldn't substituting Eq 1.54 into Eq 1.53 make the second term $\frac{\partial (T+V)}{\partial q_{i}}$ instead of $\frac{\partial(T-V)}{\partial q_{i}}$?

Comment: There are 2 minuses in eq. (1.55).

Comment: Thank you I feel silly for missing that.

Comment: Don't worry. It happens for everyone :)