# Reversed effective force in D'Alembert's Principle

Tags: forces, classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, terminology

In D'Alembert's Principle,what is reversed effective forces and how to determine it's direction?

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/175977/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/12353/2451

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a "Reversed Effective Force"?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/175977/)